Unable to save application/octet-stream (image file) to file using Java
I am using a "User-Modified Java Class" step in Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) to take an octet-stream returned via Rest API and save it to disk.  I have a working example that assumes the input is a blob (and not necessarily an octet-stream), but I haven't been able to figure out how to save the octet-stream as-is to disk while preserving the original file integrity.
I am able to save the file to disk, however the filesize is approximately 1k smaller than the original and I receive a "filetype not supported" when attempting to open the file (with extension .jpg, same as the original).
Here is the code that will save the file disk:
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{
    Object[] r = getRow();
    if (r == null) {
        setOutputDone();
    return false;
    }
    String filename = get(Fields.In, "imageFile").getString(r);
    File f = new File(filename);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try{
        if (!f.exists()){ f.createNewFile(); }
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        // this is the line I'm fidlding with...
        byte[] blobBytes = (byte[])get(Fields.In, "attachment").getBinary(r);

        bos.write( blobBytes );
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){}
        return true;
    }

Note that the snippet: get(Fields.In, "attachment") retrieves the octet-stream as raw data (contents of the Body of the Rest API response) which is read into the PDI step.
Both
byte[] blobBytes = (byte[])get(Fields.In, "attachment").getBinary(r);

and
byte[] blobBytes = get(Fields.In, "attachment").getBinary(r);

produce the same results.  I also tried writing directly to the output stream and
bos.write( (byte[])get(Fields.In, "attachment").getBinary(r) );

and
bos.write( get(Fields.In, "attachment").getBinary(r) );

produce the same results as the previous method.  At least they produce the same same size (13k) file in each case as well as the file being reported as "unsupported file type" by the image viewer.
The image is of the octet-stream as saved to a text file in case it helps...
octet-stream output as text file
and the response header information...
{""Status"":""200"",
""Transfer-Encoding"":""chunked"",
""X-AR-TR-Core-Id"":""bF1KNClCSZe6ocXTD2vdlQ"",
""X-AR-TR-Counter"":""1"",
""X-Content-Type-Options"":""nosniff"",
""Date"":""Wed, 03 Apr 2024 02:48:19 GMT"",
""X-Frame-Options"":""SAMEORIGIN"",
""Strict-Transport-Security"":""max-age=31622400; includeSubDomains"",
""Cache-Control"":""no-store"",
""Content-Security-Policy"":""frame-ancestors 'self'"",
""Content-Disposition"":""attachment ;filename=CA-1N CB F504168.jpg"",
""Set-Cookie"":""_cacheId=279713"",
""Vary"":""Accept-Encoding, User-Agent"",
""Expires"":""Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"",
""X-XSS-Protection"":""1; mode=block"",
""Content-Type"":""application\/octet-stream""}

My Java expertise is minimal, so any help is most appreciated.
--Ezra

"all but non-existent" means it's existent...

@WalterTross For a discrete quantity yes, for a continuous quantity no. Java knowledge is more a continuous quantity.

@WalterTross fair enough, edited for clarity

Try it without the base64 decoder. NB The createNewFile() call is worse than useless here.

thanks @user207421, I think I'm realizing that the octet-stream is binary and not Base64, so I've removed the Base64 conversion.  I still am unable to create the files faithfully - the file sizes are almost the same sizes as the originals, but about 1k smaller in the final product.  I've reverted to the original and will update the question with the latest so as not to confuse others ...or most likely myself :-)

You need to find out how the file is being sent. Have a look at the response headers. Compare the binary with the expected data. And remove the exists()/createNewFile()!

@user Updated to include the response header information.  I also removed the 'if file exists/creatNewFile' and it didn't seem to make any difference.  Not sure what you mean by "compare the binary with the expected data" - is there a specific check that you are referring to?   I'm expecting binary data from the application/octet-stream and trying to throw that onto the disk with a shiny new name "<sum_file>.jpg", but obviously there is something I'm missing.  Probably lots more, but that's for another time...

I mean compare the data you expect with the data you actually get. Somebody somewhere is mangling it, and it isn't (now) this code. Adding or removing the (byte[]) cast won't do anything: obviously it really is a byte[], otherwise you would get a ClassCastException. I'm wondering what the sending code is doing, too. And don't save blob data 'in a text file'. It isn't text.

NB File.exists() searches the directory; File.createNewFile() searches the directory to test for pre-existence, creates and opens the file, and closes it; new FileOutputStream() searches the directory for pre-existence, deletes the file if present, and creates and opens the new file. You can see that you are at least doubling the work with the !exists()/createNewFile() code.

ok, thanks @user207421, I think the issue is with PDI and the RestClient step.  I think that the step might be reading in the response body as a string instead of binary, which could be causing the issue.  I'll start picking at that thread.  And thanks for the explanation of the !exists/createNewFile() code!
